# Loading second stylesheet not working (Shopify)

Tags: css, sass, shopify

I'm trying to load a second stylesheet in Shopify, exactly the same way the current stylesheet is loaded.

Currently I have "theme.scss.liquid" which is in asset folder and called in theme.liquid this way :

```
{{ 'theme.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

Now I created "underthefold.scss.liquid" in asset folder and call it in theme.liquid as :

```
{{ 'underthefold.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

The new stylesheet is not loading, returning status 422, not processable. What do I miss here ?

Side note : the purpose of this second stylesheet is to load "under the fold content" a bit later, thus eliminating render blocking ressources. I hope that's the correct way to do it.

Comment: Is the file empty or there is already some code in it? Are you sure that the SCSS code is valid?

Comment: Okay I just got it to work! Silly mistake. I did not realize rules predefined in the first stylesheet could not apply in the second stylesheet. Therefore some piece of code like: @include media-query($small) {height:initial;} could not work. It was solved after I commented these out.